# ReactJS: Expected property shorthand object-shorthand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a form with a submit. When it is clicked I create an object to send these data to POST.

So I have saveEntity const:

```
const saveEntity = (event, errors, values) => {

  // this is the const that is signed as error:
        const valoreComune: any = comCod ? { comCod: { comCod: comCod } } : personEntity.comCod ? { comCod: { comCod: personEntity.comCod.comCod } } : { comCod: null };
  //....

const entity = {  // this is the object that I pass to post
  // ....
  valoreComune
}
}
```

I need to recreate this object structure:

```
comCod: {
   comCod: value
}
```

or

```
comCod: null
```

Now I receive this error:

> Expected property shorthand  object-shorthand

Now usually i resolve writing directly in this way:

```
const entity = { 
      valoreComune
    }
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the object-shorthand syntax for this part:

```
{ comCod: { comCod: comCod } }
```

Which is written like so:

```
{ comCod: { comCod } }
```